# Incompatible pointer types warning (in Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, types, variable-assignment, compiler-warnings

I'm still a bit green in iOS development and keep getting a warning that I'm not sure about.

I am using a custom cell in a tableview and have set its class to be a subclass of UITableViewCell called SiteCell. In my "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method when I declare the selected cell as a SiteCell type, I receive the following warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing SiteCell __strong with an
>   expression of type UITableViewCell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SiteCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *rowIdentity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    [selectedRows setObject:[cell.siteTitleLabel text] forKey:rowIdentity];

    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that cellForRowAtIndexPath is properly coded, and is known to always return a `SiteCell`, you simply need to cast to `SiteCell*`:

```
SiteCell *cell = (SiteCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be this since you have to cast the `UITableViewCell` to your subclass `SiteCell`

```
SiteCell *cell = (SiteCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it. You need `NSIndexPath`

```
SiteCell *cell = (SiteCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
```